# How to delete a document from mongodb based on specific property value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have attuid from client that is printing `req.params.id` now i want to delete document that contains this attuid value.Below remove method is not removing the document. Any idea what is implemented wrong ?

controller.js

```
export function destroy(req, res) {
 console.log(req.params.id);
  UserAccess.remove({attuid: req.params.id});
}
```

schema.js

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

var UserAccessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  attuid: String,
  email: String,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
UserAccess.remove({attuid: req.params.id});
```

it returns an `Query` instance and does not actually performs an action.
To make it happen, you should either call `Query#exec` method:

```
UserAccess.remove({attuid: req.params.id})
    .exec(function() {
        // your callback here
    })
```

or provide a callback to `.remove`:

```
UserAccess.remove({attuid: req.params.id}, function() {
    // your callback here
});
```

Comment: Thank you it helped to understand how mongodb works in terms of callback.